# Pumping lemma for context-free languages theorical question.

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I have seen the demostration that $a^nb^nc^n$ is not a context-free languaje like a million times.

My question is: If a languaje **can** produce a word of the form $a^nb^nc^n$ it is instantanley not context-free? what happen with the words like $a^nb^nc^nd^n$?

Comment: The answer to your first question is clearly *no*: the language $\{aabbcc\}$ is regular, hence context-free. The proof that $\{a^nb^na^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not context-free can be done along the same lines as the proof that $\{a^nb^nc^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not context-free. It can also be done along the lines of the proof that I gave in my answer to your earlier question today.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you right, i just edited the post for not duplicated questions.

Comment: The proof for $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a very minor modification of the proof for $\{a^nb^nc^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: I think an alternative to @BrianM.Scott's very minor modification would be to show that, if you had a context-free grammar for $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, then you could get one for $\{a^nb^nc^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ by just deleting $d$ wherever it appears in a production.